# Web browser in Windows Form not allowing ctrl+c when using Form. show()

Tags: c#, forms, xaml, webbrowser-control

I have an xaml screen that launches a Windows Form with the web browser  control. When I use `ShowDialog()`, the shortcut keys work fine, however when I change to use `Show()`, the controls no longer work.

Comment: Forms (winforms?) and Xaml (WPF) are different things - please clarify which you're using and also which web browser device is embedded

Comment: The web browser is on the Windows Form (winform) and is being shown from an XAML (WPF).